# I deleted my post. And now?

Tags: discussion, deletion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I recently deleted one of my own posts so I can ask the question again and maybe drive more attention to it, since I put much effort into it.
But it seems like deleting a post does not really delete the question, does it?

Is there a specific time you have to wait until you can repost your deleted question?

Comment: The amount of appropriate time to wait before reposting a question that you simply deleted for lack of exposure is 500 years. Of course, if you had found some problems with the formulation of the question, and decided to change it, it is appropriate to ***edit*** the question instead.

Comment: And what is the point of editing a question no one will ever see, because?

Comment: It's never appropriate to *delete a question in order to so repost the question again.*  Doing so defies site policies.  Instead, (1) edit your post to improve it, (2) wait a smidgen of time, (3) if, after waiting a week, with no response, even after having edited it, you are free to offer a bounty on it.  Deleting in order to repost amounts to a sort of "gaming" the system.  And no, deleting a post does not really delete the question.  Be careful, too many deleted, downvoted, and/or closed posts puts any user at risk of receiving a question(answer) block.  So, just don't make a it a habit.

Comment: "The amount of appropriate time to wait before reposting a question that you simply deleted for lack of exposure is 500 years." So, in a few weeks, it will be appropriate for Martin Luther to repost the 95 theses. [Although I don't think he could complain about lack of exposure.]

Comment: In any case, I think it's a good thing you asked here, now.  Thanks for the question.

Comment: FYI you have the necessary rep required to post a [bounty](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), which is what I usually do. (if you are so worried about losing rep over posting the bounty, I'm probably willing to provide a bounty to your question.)

Comment: I am willing to provide a bounty to my questions, but when ever I did I just got short "answers" to my questions which did not really helped and seemed more like someone just wanted the bounty. I just think, that "older" questions have no real chance to still get an answer, which is sad. Espacially when you took effort in posting.

Comment: In any case, deleting a question removes all chance of it being answered. Reposting a deleted question will likely, as mentioned, bring negative attention...

Comment: Ok. I will not do that anymore. Actually I thought that the option to delete your post is so you can get a "second chance". @Simply Beautiful Art: If you are willing to give a bounty on the question, I am talking about this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458571/p-adic-arithmetic-cauchy-sequence-polynomial. Of course you dont have to, but I would like to get an indepth answer, or hints to work with in the comments. The question has been viewed 24 times in 24 hours :O.

Comment: =P you'll have to wait a bit, bounties cannot be placed on very new questions.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank you very much for providing a bounty to the question!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Moderators and users with sufficiently high reputation can see deleted posts. But the point of deleting a post is for the post to be deleted. Please don't delete a question just so you can repost it later. If you want to change a question, edit it. If you want to get more attention for your question, you can find some pointers [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question). It also helps to have some patience, it can take many hours or even days until a question is answered, especially when the topic is slightly advanced.

Comment: "It also helps to have some patience, it can take many hours or even days until a question is answered, especially when the topic is slightly advanced."  Indeed, which is another reason for folks to *not post questions at the last minute*.

Comment: It is not a last minute question.

Comment: @Corn, good to know you're not part of the "but I have a deadline hlp me plz!!1!" crowd, then. Still, as already noted, patience is a virtue.

Comment: Well, I just think there is something not quite healthy with the question-answer system here. I do not want to cry about my question not getting an answer immediatly, but I highly doubt, that I would receive an answer. The question got viewed 30 times. That is sad and this site is not really "friendly" to answers that are yet to be answered. Reputations are hard to earn when you are not able to answer alot of questions and users are quick to downvote but hasitant to upvote. There should be other ways to drive attention to questions.