# How to get viewing for a new answer to an old posted question?

Tags: discussion

I intended to post a question, but found it had been posted on MSE months ago and received several answers, all up-voted though none yet accepted. Thinking it over, I discovered my own answer to the question and posted it.  But who will see it? The OP will see it, and I'm allowed to alert one other who has posted a comment or answer to the question. Is there a recognized way to get a wider viewing?  Normally I follow only new and recent questions, and suppose most others do the same. Does that mean I'm most likely talking to myself when I attempt to answer an old question?

Comment: An older post: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478) Other posts [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478) might be of interest, too.

Comment: When you answer a question, it gets bumped up to the top of the active questions list.

Comment: @QUDIT--Thanks, I forgot the active questions list.

Comment: @Qudit you should leave that as an answer so that this question can be marked as answered.

Comment: @StelkaBiderman Ok, I've made it into an answer.

Comment: The active tab is not of much use because it quickly gets out of it due to high traffic, so practically only few people will see it. And those few who will look at it will most likely just look at the already highest rated answer(s), so more honest answer to this is: No, the site has no good mechanism to get views to your new answer (no matter how good it is), unfortunately. It has mechanism to get views to other people answers though (such as bounty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you answer a question, it gets bumped up to the top of the active questions list.

Comment: Although, as OP writes, "Normally I follow only new and recent questions, and suppose most others do the same." Those who have their preferences set to "recent" or "newest" instead of "active" will not see the new answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sure, but there isn't a way for a question to be moved higher up under newest anyway as far as I am aware.