# Non-OP bumping a question

Tags: discussion

I am working on a Java algorithm to plot multiple hyperbolas at different angles.   To help with that I googled and stumbled on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2707394/rotation-of-hyperbola-with-any-angle).

My old and tired brain doesn't think I can do the substitutions properly (it seems easy but I think there might be some gotchas in there).   So I would really benefit from the final answer, but I don't know how to bump somebody else's question to see if I can get someone to post the actual answer and not just hints on how to get to it.

Is it okay to bump somebody else's almost answered question?

How would I do that, if it's okay?

Comment: The most effective way would be to offer a bounty, or share it with social media, or both.  The resulting attention should bump the question's visibility.

Comment: I avoid social media like the plague, but I didn't realize I could start a bounty on someone else's question.   I will do that!

Comment: I have provided [a community-wiki answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2707394/rotation-of-hyperbola-with-any-angle/2921937#2921937) to it. Hope it is useful to you.

Comment: This is perhaps related: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478) (And also [the posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, I know how to bump _my_ old question.  It was not so clear to me how to appropriately bump someone else's question.

Comment: I think the most effective strategy is to post a question on meta asking how you can give it attention :)

Comment: @TreFox It worked.