# Why are my questions hardly answered?

Tags: discussion

I like to think that I explained questions quite clearly yet I feel like the exposure of my question is quite low, reflected by the views of each question. There are hardly any comments or hints related to my question, I was wondering how can I get more attention on my questions? I feel like I might be doing something wrong, which is leading to less exposure. 
(I am sorry if it sounds like I take this site for granted, that is definitely not my intention, but if I could get more helps from this site, I will be more than delighted!)

Comment: This looks like a possible duplicate of [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your title says, "Why are my questions hardly answered?"  Your first Question was posted on March 18 of this year (a month ago), and in all you have posted fourteen Questions.  Of these:

- four have no answer
- four have exactly one answer
- six have more than one answer

I further note that you did not accept any Answer to any of your Questions.

Given this situation I wonder if you are perhaps asking about problems which you don't understand well enough to appreciate any of the solutions offered.  However it doesn't seem to me that overall your Questions have suffered from a lack of attention.

Comment: How would accepting answers change the situation?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that you are acting much like none of your Questions was answered, but I don't see why you have that impression.  Did you find the Answers posted overly terse?  Were they worded in a fashion that was too advanced or too elementary?  Was there a missing step in each Answer?  Focusing on details of one example (none are articulated in you Question here on Meta) might provide a clearer setup for Readers.

Comment: All I really asked was how to get more attention on it, you acting like this is a complaint or a criticism about the site, which is definitely not my intention as I clearly stated in the beginning. If this **is** the usual level of attention for a user like me then so be it. Also I have no idea where your idea of me 'not understanding my own questions well and not appreciating the answers' coming from, I upvoted ones that i found helpful and interesting, so I feel like that is not the case.

Comment: Voting is anonymous, so I had no idea about that.  However your Question above has a title about your questions being "hardly answered," so I tried to address that.

Comment: Alright, fair enough, I try to accept the best answer next time round, thank you for your help

Comment: If you find an answer helpful (or one that is most helpful among several), then accepting it is appropriate. If not, you might edit the Question itself to give more context for what further information would make for a helpful Answer.

Comment: You don't have to wait until "next time around" to accept an answer, JustWandering. You can go back to those ten questions of yours that already have answers, and decide whether any of them are worth accepting (and if they aren't worth accepting, you can leave comments or edit the questions to indicate what more you need).

Comment: @JustWandering I'm curious why you deleted all of your 4 unanswered questions...

Comment: That is because it is not helping the further Readers since they do not have answers on it. @AndrewT.

Comment: @JustWandering Well, there's no sense of urgency on SE networks. Anyone can answer any on-topic questions at any time (even after 1 years later). But it's up to you if you don't want to get answers on your deleted questions, or if you feel your questions won't really help other people...