# Asking a question which is pretty much a dupe

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, exact-duplicates

I want to ask a question, but it is basically a duplicate of a (5 year old) question already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/861557/29123) and that question doesn't have an answer. Morally, any good answer to that question would be an answer to my question, although I plan on having a bit more context which specifically emphasize I would prefer a geometric/topological approach as an answer (also I add why I don't think one of the comments on that question would be a good answer). Since I am being somewhat more specific in what I am looking for, I would have relevant tags which are not obviously related the original question (to hopefully attract people from those areas). Due to the above, I think that adding my context to their question would change theirs a bit to much.

**Question:** Would it be better to put a bounty on it and maybe add some geometry/topology tags or re-ask the question with the additional context I am interested in?

EDIT: I have updated the original question, to view it in the original state you can [view the history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/861557/revisions)

Comment: I would suggest that editing the question to clarify it and to add tags would be an excellent first step---the edit will bump the question to the top of the list of active questions.  Posting a bounty would be a good second step.

Comment: Related: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478) (And maybe also some [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478).)

Comment: Okay, I think I thought of a way to add context that doesn't take away from the original question/change focus but suggest there could be a topological/geometric way of approaching it (and make some other suggestions). I will start off with what you suggest @XanderHenderson.

Comment: On the other hand, if you are asking a question which requires that much editing, you could also ask a new question.  Cite the old one, explain how what you want is different, and point out that the older question has no answer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson The editing mostly is just adding context and potential directions. If people thinks it changes it too much I can also rollback and ask a new one

Comment: The question as it is now is basically the question I would have written, except I would write a bit more on why I think a geometric/topological viewpoint would make sense and make it clear I am more interested in that direction.

Comment: Let's see if a fat bounty can draw in an answer to this edited version.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Thanks, hopefully that will attract some good attention!