# Why are people downvoting my question?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, down-votes

My question [Coming up with a rigorous definition for a Riemman-like sum which is easier to compute?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655102/coming-up-with-a-rigorous-defintion-for-a-riemman-like-sum-which-is-easier-to-co)
 has been downvoted twice. Is it because:

a) My question is too similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637157/how-do-prove-the-darboux-like-sum-of-a-function-defined-on-a-countable-set-with)?

b) I ask to many meta stack questions?

c) My question is unclear. (In that case, what exactly is unclear? Is it the sub-interval? The partition? The counting function of $n\prime$?)

d) [The previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637157/how-do-prove-the-darboux-like-sum-of-a-function-defined-on-a-countable-set-with) was already understood. In that case, how do I improve the definition? It is clearly not rigorous.

Comment: Maybe the tag ([meta-tag:specific-question]) would be reasonable here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Relatively long question often do not fare so well. Especially if they are somewhat open-ended. The site works best for clear-cut and directly answerable questions.

That said, I think actually "b" might play a role by now, and it would be best to steer clear of this.

Study

[How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

and maybe also

[How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question)

Going forward please avoid asking so many meta question about your questions. If you want to talk about your posts, you could try chat. Maybe you find some like-minded users. Of course also there it can be useful not to insist too much on ones own interests but it is overall more informal and such things are perceived as less of a distraction.

Answer (score 1):

Arbuja, glad to see you took out the language that was dismissive of your tutor and added a graceful acknowledgement for the help you got from WillieWong. I changed my down-vote to an up-vote, as those were the things that caused me to down-vote it.

I hope you get more responses and input from this second post, and keep posting interesting questions.

(I will add that I haven't read your post in full -- it's kind of long. How you write up math is more a matter of personal style, but I think you might get more engagement if you try to make your posts a bit more concise and straight-forward. Communicating one's mathematical ideas is a different skill from devising and solving math questions, and sharing them on math.se can be a good way to work on honing that skill.)