# Answering my own question to attract attention.

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

Sometimes I have a question and have an idea how to answer it. I'm pretty sure **(see edit 1)** the idea is correct but not so sure **(see edit 1)**. However, I do want to be so sure **(see edit 1)**, so I ask online. When there are no answers even after a bounty, may I just transfer my idea from the post to an answer? Of course the answer is not necessarily correct, but I think it's a good way to attract attention ASSUMING it's not against the rules. (Of course there's always going to overflow.)

One thing to note is that if I delete the idea from the question post instead of just copying the idea to answer, then question post becomes shorter and therefore hopefully gives more incentive to answer (or comment on my answer).

Edit 1: Sureness is relative. This is of course the whole idea of hypothesis testing in statistics. How sure must I be to answer my own question in this regard? 95%? 99%?

Edit 2: Thank you just_floating for introducing me to this term: [Cunningham's Law](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law).

Edit 3: [Jonas Meyer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3480/733302) says

> If you have worked out an answer to your question, you can also post it as an answer. If you're not yet sure it's correct, you could start with a disclaimer to that effect, and ask for feedback.

Edit 4: Does it make any difference if I do community wiki?

Comment: That seems to be an attempt to "get around" rules, or game the system, for the purpose of "attracting attention".  I would not advise doing so.  You can offer a bounty again, if you offer a higher bounty than you may have previously offered.  No one should post any "maybe this might work?" questions as answers.

Comment: @amWhy thanks for commenting. Actually something I didn't really clear up in the post initially is that sureness is relative. This is of course the whole idea of hypothesis testing in statistics. How sure must I be to answer my own question in this regard? 95%? 99%? I'll now edit my post in this regard

Comment: This is - to some extent - related: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478) And you might also be interested in some of the [other posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478).

Comment: If you are asking a question, and seek verification, use the solution-verification tag, after stating the problem and posting you solution.  Answer fields are not intended for others to evaluate.  That's the purpose of the solution-verification/proof-verification tag: you post a proposed solution in the question, and ask if it is correct, and if not, where did you go wrong.  Do not use answer fields for others to have to evaluate.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks! Do you disagree with [Jonas Meyer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3480/733302)? 'If you have worked out an answer to your question, you can also post it as an answer. If you're not yet sure it's correct, you could start with a disclaimer to that effect, and ask for feedback.'

Comment: You need to stop posting multiple questions in the multiple questions that you post: Part 1, Part 2, Part 3, about the same question, in each of which you post multiple questions.

Comment: I think the third edit from 'Jonas Meyer' doesn't answer the question at all. The question talks about moving attempted solution to an answer from the initial post. The comment from 'Jonas Meyer' talks about the case in which 'you have worked out an answer to your question'. I think this should be clarified, because the two situations have different answers.

Comment: @just_floating It sounds like you're focusing on the first sentence of the quote. What about the second sentence of the quote? 'If you're not yet sure it's correct, you could start with a disclaimer to that effect, and ask for feedback.' What's the difference between the 2 situations?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon  You expressed your motivation in the title of your question: you are seeking to gain attention to your unfocused questions, and answering when you are so unsure, just to bump the post:  therein lies the problem.

Comment: @amWhy I am not so unsure. That would be wrong. I'm asking when I am not so sure. Absence of evidence vs evidence of absence. I am not 99.99% sure, but I am 99% sure. Can I post an answer for 99% sure? How about 98%? 95%? I already clarified this part of sureness in 'Edit 1'

Comment: You have made it clear you are going to do what you want to do, regardless of input from users to your particular questions, @John.  I'll speak not further here with you, because I think you did not ask this question in good faith.

Comment: @amWhy Eh. 'It's either legal or it isn't.' to quote a character from an episode of the TV series hustle

Comment: @amWhy Well it's the jonas meyer answer that imnsho answers my question, but in your opinion it doesn't answer my question. Shall you take this as a no?

Comment: [Jonas Meyer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3480/733302) says > If you have worked out an answer to your question, you can also post it as an answer. If you're not yet sure it's correct, you could start with a disclaimer to that effect, and ask for feedback.

Comment: @MiloBrandt My question is when i do what you describe and there are no answers even after a bounty, can i just change 'is this solution correct?' to 'how do you do this?" and then post my solution as an answer in order to attract more attention?

Comment: @MartinSleziak does it make any difference if I do community wiki? edited post.

Comment: I see you made an minor update to a fairly complicated 6 month old closed question, and that bumped it to the top and got my attention. Stop that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that you should answer your own question if you aren't sure if you are correct (without stating that it could be wrong). I also don't think that you should delete your question because someone could be in the middle of typing it or stumble upon the problem and use your previously done work to help them.

I think if you want to attract attention you should use the reputation bounty. I'm not sure what to do if no one does the bounty.

This is an application of Cunningham's law but I think this acts to the detriment of other users.

Comment: Thank you just_floating for introducing me to this term: [Cunningham's Law](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law).

Comment: Oh I didn't say delete question. I said delete the idea from the question post i.e. cut and paste into the answer post instead of copy and paste into the answer post.

Comment: Anyway thanks for answering. Actually something I didn't really clear up in the post initially is that sureness is relative. This is of course the whole idea of hypothesis testing in statistics. How sure must I be to answer my own question in this regard? 95%? 99%? I'll now edit my post in this regard

Comment: Do you disagree with [Jonas Meyer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3480/733302)? 'If you have worked out an answer to your question, you can also post it as an answer. If you're not yet sure it's correct, you could start with a disclaimer to that effect, and ask for feedback.'

Comment: I think that is fine if you explain that it isn't necessarily correct.

Comment: Wait seriously, that's it? This one tiny thing that is completely reasonable and agreeable turns your answer 360? ok....

Comment: I misunderstood the premise. Your work on an answer that may be wrong could help a lot a future user without confusing them by them thinking it is definitely correct.

Comment: The premise is stated in the title.  Answering one's own posts *to attract attention* is not a valid reason for answering one's own posts.  And Adding only the words "not really sure..." does not make a guess at an answer okay, in order to seek feedback.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. @amWhy Do you disagree with Jonas Meyer?

Comment: I think this question needs a rewrite. If progress has been made and someone could help then it is in a way a different question as the context has changed although whether this warrants attention is hard to judge without an example. Attracting attention when nothing has changed is not appropriate.

Comment: No, I think you are taking Jonas's answer out of context.  At any rate, I do not agree with his answer as you seem to interpret it, not when you are as unsure of your answers as you were on the two of your multiple-questions-in-one-posts

Comment: @amWhy But you agree with Jonas Meyer's answer in your interpretation?

Comment: just_floating and cc @amWhy: 'Attracting attention when nothing has changed is not appropriate. ' Then why don't I just not include an idea at all, even if I have one, at first and then later add an idea so that the edit will bump the post? I mean theoretically, I may just not have had the idea in the first place.

Comment: Then edit the *question*!  And start by asking only one question per post, instead of multiple questions in each post.

Comment: @amWhy wait what? but pointless minor edits just for the sake of bumping is really the one against the rules right?

Comment: @amWhy and just_floating, does it make any difference if I do community wiki? edited post.